# ActiveMQ message grouping performance

Tags: jms, message-queue, messaging, activemq-classic

Has anyone used the Message Grouping feature in ActiveMQ?

http://activemq.apache.org/message-groups.html

This would be a really useful feature for a project I'm working on, but I'm curious how well this feature scales and performs.  In our system, we would need to group messages into groups of about 3-5 messages, so we would be continuously adding groups as the process runs.  In this case, it seems like we'd eventually just run out of memory trying to store all the groups.

I'm interested in any experiences/thoughts/pros/cons.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've used Message Groups on many projects and it works great. Though for full disclosure I was one of the folks pushing for Message Groups and did much of the initial implementation work.

The use case of Message Groups came from partitioning large topic hierarchies; such as dealing with financial stock symbols and the like. We wanted message groups to be able to use very fine grained correlation expressions (JMSXGroupID strings) - so you could use the date, stock symbol and product type as groupID - or the customer or business transaction ID or whatever.

To avoid having to keep every group ID string in memory, the default provider uses hash buckets - so we only store the mapping of hash buckets to consumers - not the individual strings. So it scales to as many group IDs as you want to use! It also means we don't have to 'clean' the old message group IDs out etc

Comment: suppose the `JMSXGroupID` is equal to some no i.e. 3345. Then all the messages with `JMSXGroupID` = 3345 will go to the same consumer. But suppose i dynamically add a new  consumer than how the activeMq ensures to send the 3345 message to same old consumer (as you are telling it stores the hash of the id). Thanks.

Comment: I don't quite understand why using hash replace each GroupID string would be effective? Is hash value very small? But what if I have one million new GroupIDs every day?